# Unreachable code when I'm already calling it

Tags: java, unreachable-code

I have to do some kind of Google Maps like program on Java, I have the following code:

```
public double CGlon(double graus, double min, double sec)
    {
        double min2;
        graus =(int) longitud;
        min = (longitud - graus)*60;
        min2 = (int) min;
        sec = (min-min2)*60;
        return(graus);
        return(min); //Unreachable point
        return(sec); //Error
    }
```

where I have to convert the coordinates, 41,234234º into 41º 23' 122" , for example. And I'm calling on the main program:

```
public class GPS {

private static final int graus = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TempClass lloc1 = new TempClass();
    TempClass lloc2 = new TempClass();
    TempClass lloc3 = new TempClass();
    TempClass lloc4 = new TempClass();

//Inicialitzacio de les dades
    //ETSE
    lloc1.nomSet("ETSE");
    lloc1.latitudSet(41.1258048);
    lloc1.longitudSet(1.2385834);

System.out.println(lloc1.CGlat(graus, 0, 0)+" graus"+lloc1.CGlat(0, 0, 0)+" minuts y "+lloc1.CGlat(0, 0, 0)+" segons de latitud.");
```

the problem is that i'm having an unreachable error on the 'min' variable and i dont know why.

Comment: You can return once, if you want to return as per some condition then pass it in some `if` or etc.

Comment: First, that isn't legal Java code, **return** is a keyword not a method.  Second, what happens when you return a value from a method?  What line does the JVM want to execute next?

Answer (score 2):

The first `return` statement stops execution of the method, so the second and third `return` statements cannot be reached. If you're trying to return three values, return an array:

```
public double[] CGlon(double graus, double min, double sec)
{
    double min2;
    graus =(int) longitud;
    min = (longitud - graus)*60;
    min2 = (int) min;
    sec = (min-min2)*60;
    return new double[] { graus, min, sec };
}
```

Comment: @manutheking - It looks like you're printing the array object itself. This will print the identity hash of the array, not it's values. Try printing the relevant element(s) using subscripts or else use `Arrays.toString(CGlon(...))` to print the entire array as a readable string.

Comment: after do this it shows no error but after compiling and running i get this on the console: 

    
`[D@79b0edb2 º[D@4ec57f88 '[D@837e21f ''<br/>
`    [D@cde6570 graus de longitud.' `

Comment: @manutheking - Um, didn't you just post that comment and then delete it? See my comment just above.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I just messed up with the comment. It works fine now but it displays the 3 variables in a row. Is there any thing I can do to just show 1 of the variables?

Comment: @manutheking - Sure. If you want to display, for instance, the second element (`min`), you can print the element at index 0; for instance: `System.out.println("min=" + CGlon(0, 0, 0)[1]);`.

Answer (score 1):

A function (or method) can only *return* once.  How do you expect this to work?:

```
return(graus);
return(min); //Unreachable point
return(sec); //Error
```

As soon as the first `return` is executed, the function has ended.  It has resulted in a value and is done executing.  So nothing *after* a `return` statement will ever be executed.

If you want to return three separate values, create a data structure of some kind which holds those three values together and return an instance of that structure.  It might look something like:

```
public class SomeDataStructure {
    private final double graus;
    private final double min;
    private final double sec;

    public SomeDataStructure(double graus, double min, double sec) {
        this.graus = graus;
        this.min = min;
        this.sec = sec;
    }

    // also create getters for the values
}
```

Then in your code:

```
SomeDataStructure result = new SomeDataStructure(graus, min, sec);
return result;
```

Comment: @manutheking: As you learn, be aware of the pros and cons of the different solutions offered in the different answers here. Returning an array of values requires less code and is *initially* simpler, but creates no semantic link between the values themselves. In a small case, it's fine. As code increases in complexity, strongly-typed objects present more semantic clarity of the logic of the system, as well as a single place to update logic. There's even an explicit refactoring pattern to move from an array to an object: http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceArrayWithObject.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect that code to do? Why do you have 3 return statements?

Once you return a value, the method does not continue executing. You have other statements after a return value, which is by definition invalid, hence the error.

It seems like you're trying to return more than one value, which isn't possible. Instead, wrap the 3 return values into an Object and return that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
return(graus);
return(min);
return(sec);
```

When the method is executed, it returns a value to the caller when it encounters the first `return` statement. There is no way for the method to return any other value. Consider the calling code

```
double result = lloc1.CGlat(graus, 0, 0);
```

What value would `result` be assigned in your case? The first, second, or third return value? Therefore, your code does not compile.

Now, if you want to return three values from a method, what you really want to do is return a compound object. To that end, create a suitable class to hold your values:

```
return new Location(graus, min, sec);
```

where the `Location` class assigns these to fields that you can query from the calling code, e.g. like so:

```
Location result = lloc1.CGlat(graus, 0, 0);
System.out.println(result.getGraus() + "°" + result.getMinutes() + "'" + result.getSeconds() + "\"");
```